# bjam execution in boost's example/tutorial failed

Tags: boost-python, bjam

As instructed on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/hello.html

I entered `bjam` in the folder's directory (C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_65_1\libs\python\example\tutorial) and got the following error:

```
...found 12 targets...
...updating 5 targets...
compile-c-c++ hello.obj
hello.cpp
hello.cpp(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/python/module.hpp': No such file or directory

    call "C:\Users\trg\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.1_vcvars32_.cmd" >nul
cl /Zm800 -nologo @"hello.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ hello.obj...
...skipped <p.>hello_ext.dll for lack of <p.>hello.obj...
...skipped <p.>hello_ext.pdb for lack of <p.>hello.obj...
...skipped <p.>hello for lack of <p.>hello_ext.dll...
...failed updating 1 target...
...skipped 4 targets...
```

As the above returns, the error is: `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/python/module.hpp': No such file or directory`. The boost C++ library was successfully installed with `bjam`. I use Eclipse to edit C++ and all `#include <boost/whatever>` lines seem to be able to compile without error.

Anyone has any suggestion on how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the file C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_65_1\libs\python\example\Jamroot by uncommenting the <include> statement and changing it as follows:

```
project
  : requirements
  <include>../../..
  <library>boost_python
;
```

Comment: Unfortunately same results.. Think it is the user.config.jam, but no idea on how to edit the file

Comment: Is the error message exactly the same or do you just get a different kind of error? When I remove my user-config.jam I get errors like `warning: no Python configured in  user-config.jam` and `warning: No toolsets are configured`.